# Reusable/Shared Angular material autocomplete returns null even after selection even with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-material, components, reusability

I have implemented a shared/reusable angular material autocomplete, which uses values from a server returned as objects. I can integrate it into other components. However, if I use my component:

```
<app-positions-input [formControl]="form.controls.position"></app-positions-input>
```

the `form.control.position` returns `null`. But if I integrate like this:

```
<app-positions-input #positionComponent></app-positions-input>
```

The `positionComponent.control.value` returns the selected value. I can't make this reusable autocomplete integrate with the rest of the reactive form. `positionComponent` is basically this: `@ViewChild(PositionsComponent) positionComponent: PositionsComponent;` in the parent. But this does not work well, as I can't validate the form, since the control is not part of the reactive form.

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PositionService } from '../position.service';
import { MaterialModule } from '@myapp/client/material';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { PositionGetDto as GetDto } from '@myapp/dtos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-positions-input',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule, AsyncPipe],
  templateUrl: './positions.component.html',
  styleUrl: './positions.component.scss',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => PositionsComponent),
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})

export class PositionsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Output() selected = new EventEmitter<GetDto>();

  control = new FormControl<GetDto | undefined>(undefined);
  items: GetDto[] = [];
  filteredItems: Observable<GetDto[]>;

  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

  private onChangeCallback: (_: GetDto | undefined) => void = () => {};
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {};

  constructor(private service: PositionService) {
    this.filteredItems = this.control.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        // tap((term) => { console.log("Term: %s", term); }),
        startWith(''),
        map(item => (item ? this._filter(item) : this.items.slice()))
      );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((items) => {
      this.items = items;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
  
  writeValue(item: GetDto | undefined): void {
    this.control.setValue(item);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    //this.disabled = isDisabled;
  }

  private _filter(term: any): GetDto[] {
    let filteredItems: GetDto[];

    if (typeof term === 'object' && 'id' in term && 'name' in term) {
      filteredItems = this.items;
      return filteredItems;
    } else if (typeof term === 'string') {
      const lowerCaseTerm = term.toLowerCase();
      filteredItems = this.items.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowerCaseTerm)
      );
      return filteredItems;
    }
    return this.items;
  }

  display(item: GetDto): string {
    return item ? item.name : '';
  }

  setValue(item: GetDto | undefined) {
    this.selected.emit(item);
    this.control.setValue(item);
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Position: </mat-label>
  <input matInput aria-label="Position" placeholder="Please put a position" [formControl]="control"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="display">
    @for (item of filteredItems | async; track item) {
    <mat-option [value]="item">{{item.name}}</mat-option>
    }
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

I wonder, what am I doing wrong? I was not able to find a suitable reusable/shared autocomplete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually call your `onChangesCallback()` with the value you want reflected in the model.  So you could add a method like this:

```js
  onOptionSelected(option: GetDto) {
    this.onChangeCallback(option);
  }
```

And fire it from your template like this (*or whatever appropriate event you want to emit the value*):

```html
<mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event.option.value)">
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78183558?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpositions%2Fpositions.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpositions%2Fpositions.component.ts) example.

---

Also, instead of using your own "unsubscribe subject", you can use the new [`takeUntilDestroyed()`](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed) operator.  But even simpler, you can just leave your `items` as an observable to avoid explicitly subscribing:

```js
  items$: Observable<GetDto[]> = this.service.getAll();

  filteredItems$: Observable<GetDto[]> = this.items$.pipe(
    switchMap(allItems => this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(term => (term ? this._filter(allItems, term) : allItems.slice()))
    ))
  );
```

Notice here instead of subscribing to the `service.getAll()` then storing the emission to a separate `items` variable, we can just declare an observable that emits the items, then delcare the `filteredItems$` to begin with that.

This is much simpler because you don't need

- to subscribe
- to unsubscribe (*nor need a Subject to trigger*)
- to implement ngOnInit
- to implement ngOnDestroy

Here's a simplified [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78183558-simplified?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpositions%2Fpositions.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpositions%2Fpositions.component.ts) demo;

Comment: this worked for me like a charm. Thanks! I missed the `onOptionSelected` completely! Now I can work on a generic version of this. Honestly, I was expecting such a method to be required by the ControlValueAccessor. Also my code is much simpler. One additional question though: does the form control direct the setValue call to writeValue in the back?

Comment: Nevermind I was able to test this. When the parent calls setValue on a control, it ends up calling writeValue in the custom control class.